# IPv6: what is the purpose of ff00::/8 multicast routes?

Tags: networking, ipv6

On Android, whenever an IPv6 address is assigned to an interface, the kernel would automatically add a default multicast route (ff00::/8) through that interface to the routing table. These routes seem to conflict (same metric) and cannot be deleted. What is the purpose of these routes?

```
ip -6 route
ff00::/8 dev eth0  metric 256 
ff00::/8 dev v0 metric 256
```

Comment: Would not this question be a good candidate to be migrated (or re-asked) at the Network Engineering Beta site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same metric is a hint that actually it is the same adapter and `eth0` and `v0` are only separate interfaces on that adapter.  In other words a *broadcast* on one is the same as a *broadcast* on the other.

IPv6 no longer supports broadcast and applications must now use multicast.